# CSS switch toggle transition with labels inside

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I came across [this](https://codepen.io/magnificode/pen/ojYJJP) codepen involving a CSS only switch.

I've tried using that example but with inverted colors, so, white background + black font equals checked, and black background + white font equals unchecked.

However, I cannot seem to recreate the seamless transition animation that the author of the switch created for his colors. I've tried [tweaking it](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vzONbX) to work with his colors inverted, but the transition never seems to work.

I think my problem lies on this part of the SCSS, but I cannot seem to make it work.

```
& + label {
  cursor: pointer;

  &:hover {
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }

  &:after {
    background-color: none;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, if there is another CSS only way to make this exact switch with my colors work, I would also welcome that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the orig switch with inverted colors, and some minor modifications.

The orig toggle button has no default background color, so the page background shows through it. Instead the button is now wrapped to give it a default background-color; better. Also just quickly added left/right classes to the buttons to remove the middle line (ie borders). Anyways, the HTML structure can be cleaner than this.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOXwRY

The HTML:

```
<div class="btn_wrapper">
    <input id="toggle-on" class="toggle toggle-left" name="toggle" value="false" type="radio" checked>
    <label for="toggle-on" class="btn btn_left">Yes</label>

    <input id="toggle-off" class="toggle toggle-right" name="toggle" value="true" type="radio">
    <label for="toggle-off" class="btn btn_right">No</label>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body,html{
    background: #efefef;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.btn_wrapper {
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: inherit;
}

.btn{
    border: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}

.btn_left {
    border-right: 0px;
}

.btn_right {
    border-left: 0px;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle {
    display: none;
    & + label{
        cursor: pointer;
        min-width: 60px;
        &:hover{
            background: none;
            color: #999999;
        }
        &:after{
            background: #ffffff;
            content: "";
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    }
    &.toggle-left + label {
        border-right: 0;
        &:after{
            left: 100%
        }
    }
    &.toggle-right + label{
        margin-left: -5px;
        &:after{
            left: -100%;
        }
    }
    &:checked + label {
        cursor: default;
        color: #000000;
        transition: color 200ms;
        &:after{
            left: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I have to color the checked (white) label with a purple font and that brought even more confusion to me, but I'm gonna try to figure that out on my own.